# How to delete all hidden layers at once?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

Is it possible to delete all hidden layers in Illustrator at once and how would I do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's merely a yes or no question:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a script to delete all layers.

```
#target illustrator
var myDoc=app.activeDocument;
var layerCount=myDoc.layers.length;
for (var ii = layerCount - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
    var currentLayer = myDoc.layers[ii];
    currentLayer.locked = false;
    if (currentLayer.visible == false){
        currentLayer.visible = true;
        currentLayer.remove();
        }
    }
```

Note that this will not work on any hidden layer that is locked or where the group is locked that it is inside.

To install the script, just copy the code into a notepad and save it as all files and with the filename `delete_hidden_layers.jsx`.

Then drop a copy of that into your scripts folder. It can be found under

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator [YOUR VERSION]\Presets\en_[YOUR LANGUAGE]\Scripts
```

OR

```
C:\Program Filesx86\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator[YOURVERSION]\Presets\en_[YOUR LANGUAGE]\Scripts
```

---

Interestingly enough Photoshop seems to have this feature built into its functionality.

[image]

Comment: This script looks like it will unlock all layers in the document, which may not be desirable. Why not move the unlocking inside the if block to make sure it’s only hidden layers?

Answer (score 2):

**No**. The default installation of Illustrator provides no mechanism to delete layers other than manual deletion.

You may be able to use a third party script.

Answer (score 2):

To easily delete all your hidden layers:

1. Deselect everything.
2. Navigate to: 'Object' > 'Show All'. (This will both select *and* reveal all your hidden layers).
3. Click: [Delete]

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Here a script to download, similar to Ovaryraptor's, and tested as shown in this GIF:

[image: hiddenlayers]

Script:

```
#target Illustrator
var myDoc=app.activeDocument;
var layerCount=myDoc.layers.length;
for (var ii = layerCount - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
    var currentLayer = myDoc.layers[ii];
    currentLayer.locked = false;
    var subCount = currentLayer.layers.length;
    for (var ss =subCount -1; ss >= 0; ss--){
        var subLayer = currentLayer.layers[ss];
        subLayer.locked = false;
        if (subLayer.visible == false){
            subLayer.visible = true;
            subLayer.remove();
            }
        }
    if (currentLayer.visible == false){
        currentLayer.visible = true;
        currentLayer.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of adding a download link you should add the script itself to your answer. It's short enough and we don't have to worry about that link dying one day and invalidating your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Illustrator CC 2019, unselect all layers, then go to the menu Object->Show All.  Your hidden layers will appear and be selected.  Press Delete.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Click the menu above layers and there is an option to 'Delete hidden layers' [image]