# Delete all hidden actions steps

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I put this question in Adobe Photoshop Forum and [Adobe Photoshop Scripting Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2522673) more than a month ago and I didn't get any solution. I try here.

Doing actions for third-party users, in the testing process many steps and stops are created while the action progress. Once finished, the action ends with dozens of hidden steps that I must eliminate before making the delivery. This process is manual, selecting the hidden actions one by one **without any wrong step**, and deleting them. It would be great to have the option to automatically select all the hidden actions and eliminate them in a click, but apparently it doesn't exist.

Does anyone know any script or the way to make this process less tedious?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will have a more definitive answer, but there're several points.

I don't think there's an easy way to know if an action step is enabled or not. However, there's this amazing person, xbytor, who made [a huge library of different functions that he uses for his scripts](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html). For a non-developer like me they're hard to read, but it includes a particular script: ActionFileToJavaScript.jsx, that writes an atn file to a jsx file(s), including the information about status of the steps. So if I had a task like yours,

1. I'd export all actions as .atn
2. convert them to .jsx with xbytor's script
3. using a different script I'd read this file to find what steps are marked as `disabled` in which actions:

   ```
   step1();                  // Make
   step2();                  // Make
   step3();                  // Make
   step4(false, false);      // Make
   step5(false, false);      // Make
   step6(false, false);      // Make
   step7();                  // Make
   step8();                  // Make
   ```
4. using an AM code from ScriptListener I'd then remove all the marked steps:

   ```
   var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
       var ref1 = new ActionReference();
       ref1.putIndex( cTID('Cmnd'), 4 ); //index of the step to remove
       ref1.putName( cTID('Actn'), "Action 3" ); //name of the action
       ref1.putName( cTID('ASet'), "Set 1" ); //name of the action set
   desc.putReference( cTID('null'), ref1 );
   executeAction( cTID('Dlt '), desc, DialogModes.NO );
   ```

or if you're a better coder than me you can just use his `Actions` library to get information you need directly from an .atn file.

Comment: It looks very interesting, I'll take a look when I have time. I'll let you know the result.

Comment: btw I just noticed that xbytor's scripts include ``ActionFileToXML`` and  ``ActionFileFromXML``, maybe it'd be even easier to use them: convert to XML, remove the disabled xml nodes using JSX, convert the resulted XML back to ``atn`` file.

Comment: Yes, I had a quick look and saw several options, when I have something done I put it here. Thanks and let me see if this helps to accept your answer as valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible.

The whole idea of the "toggle on/off" option is so that there's a **temporary** way to (de)activate certain steps - so that you don't have to **delete** it.

---

**Q**: Can you automatically delete all (in)visible layers in Illustrator?
**A**: No, but with [scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110230/63979) it's possible.

I'm going to say the same thing applies with the actions. You may be able to get a script which will accomplish this.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.